# NoMethodError in basic scaffolded View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined, scaffolding

**I created a basic scaffold for a Foo model with a single property - bar:String**

foos/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>New foo</h1>

<% form_for(@foo) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :bar %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :bar %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', foos_path %>
```

**But I get a NoMethodError for my 'bar' property:**

```
 NoMethodError in Foos#new

Showing app/views/foos/new.html.erb where line #8 raised:

undefined method `bar' for #<Foo id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Extracted source (around line #8):

5: 
6:   <p>
7:     <%= f.label :bar %><br />
8:     <%= f.text_field :bar %>
9:   </p>
10:   <p>
11:     <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
```

**As you can see, bar the only property in my Foo model:**

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.String :bar

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :foos
  end
end
```

**And the new method in the foos_controller is from the default scaffold:**

```
  def new
    @foo = Foo.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @foo }
    end
  end
```

**Any ideas would be appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem you capitalized the word `String` in your db migration. Try it with a lower case s and force the migration to run again (`rake db:migrate:redo`, assuming that this was your latest migration, otherwise use

```
 rake db:migrate:down VERSION=29843923 && rake db:migrate:up VERSION=29843923
```

where 29843923 is your migration timestamp.).

Comment: Tried that but when I checked the database there was no bar column. Think I'm going to delete this project and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Did you executed your migration?